# How long does it take for the legendary naval mission to respawn?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My legendary naval mission failed about 20 hours ago and it still does not respawn. How long does it take for legendary mission to respawn?

Mine Heroic chest spawned instantly and I found one post about person complaining he had to wait 8+ hours for respawn.

Comment: it should take 3-4 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [last legendary naval mission](http://www.wowhead.com/mission=752/boarding-the-masters-call) which rewards [Draenic Sea Chart](http://www.wowhead.com/item=128693/draenic-sea-chart) for Master vs. Commander quest took between 24h and 36h to respawn.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe not an full answer but out of my experience the HFC chest mission respawns instant after failure.

I still wait for the legendary Mission to respawn after i failed at it 72 hours ago, but i did not find any Source of how Long the respawn takes.